# Thermal Noise in Oscillators

Tags: circuit-analysis, rf, circuit-design, noise, oscillator

let's consider this circuital model for an LC oscillator in which the parasitic resistance R is affected by thermal noise (represented here with an equivalent noise current source, according to the Hajimiri model):

[image]

I put my questions in bold inside the text of my book:

> Being \$i^2_n\$ a white Gaussian noise, it can be interpreted as the sum
>   of infinite mathematical impulses of uncorrelated current and
>   area \$qδ(t)\$.

**Why?? Why are they the product of a charge and a pulse?**

> This means that at each instant t a charge q is provided by the power
>   source. This charge will go on the terminals of the capacitor,
>   determining an instantaneous voltage variation equal to \$q/C\$.

**Why is that variation equal to q/C?**

Comment: 2) Because V=q/C is the definition of C.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to question 1) 
δ(t) has the dimension of the inverse of time 1/t. Current is charge per time step (I=Q/t). So you have to build the product of charge and the dirac pulse to get **impulses of current**.

Answer to question 2) Like Brian already mentioned: A capacitor's capacitance is defined as C=q/V. This can be explained like this: If you put a well defined amount of charge (like 1 Coulomb) into a **small** capacitor, the cap will reacto to that charge with a **huge voltage increase**. Vice-versa, if you put the same amount of charge into a **very large** capacitor, the cap will react with a **small voltage increase**. That's the linear dependence that C=Q/V stands for.

Comment: Can you explain me more in detail why the dimension of dirac pulse is time?

Comment: @StefanWyss, I think you're backwards.    The Dirac pulse (more properly the Dirac *functional*) has the property that \$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta (t) dt = 1\$  This can only be true if \$\delta (t)\$ has dimensions \$1/\mathrm{second}\$.  This is backed up by the fact that current equals charge *per unit time*, which is why charge is equal to the integral of current.

Comment: @TimWescott Your are right of course. I updated my answer, thanks for that.

Comment: @Kinka-Byo The dimension of dirac pulse is inverse of time. The dirac function is a very special mathematical object and thus is not easy to explain. But you can find a lot of infos on google.